# What does DB% mean in my log file? It is giving crazy values. How to solve the issue?

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, performance, solr

How can I reduce DB values? Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

```
Completed in 0.19635 (5 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00046 (0%) | **DB: 0.04554 (23%)** | 200 OK

Completed in 0.00470 (212 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00070 (14%) | **DB: 0.02763 (587%)** | 200 OK 

Completed in 0.00507 (197 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00079 (15%) | **DB: 0.03448 (679%)** | 200 OK 

Rendering template within layouts/small_video
Rendering videos/video_in_box
Completed in 0.00651 (153 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00097 (14%) | **DB: 0.03318 (509%)** | 200 OK
```

another one...

```
Completed in 0.00478 (209 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00085 (17%) | **DB: 0.05701 (1193%)** | 200 OK
```

Comment: The DB% is `(db_time) / (total_time) * 100` - I did the maths for one of your log lines, and it works out...  But the bigger question remains unanswered:  Why is DB time so much higher than total time (and / or why is it not included in the total time)?

Comment: and in benchmark.rb file and this is how it is calculating the DB%                                                                        def active_record_runtime(runtime)
        db_runtime    = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_runtime
        db_runtime    += @db_rt_before_render if @db_rt_before_render
        db_runtime    += @db_rt_after_render if @db_rt_after_render
        db_percentage = db_runtime * 100 / runtime
        " | DB: %.5f (%d%%)" % [db_runtime, db_percentage.to_i]
      end

Answer (score 0):

I think total time is no correct in the places where DB time is high..

Comment: we are using solr and front end is querying solr which is taking lot of time and because of this DB time is also showing high...